# using .click() + this to get carousel slide

Tags: jquery

I have found a jQuery carousel that I am currently trying to alter. The original is found at http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp I am trying to change the enable carousel indicators. The Original is

```
    $(".item0").click(function(){
            $("#myCarousel").carousel(0);
    });
    $(".item2").click(function(){
            $("#myCarousel").carousel(1);
    });
    $(".item3").click(function(){
            $("#myCarousel").carousel(2);
    });
```

I have more images than the page provided, I thought I could use a generic class, wgi, to grab it and item6. My code:

```
    $(".wgi").click(function() {
    var d = $(this).attr("class").match(/\d+/);
    var f = ".item" + d;

        alert(d + ", " +f);

    $.fn.moveFn = function(){$("#myCarousel").carousel(d)}
    $(f).moveFn(d);

       alert(d +"b");
    }
```

The alerts work but the function I think I built does not. Any idea?

Comment: can you please create JSFIDDLE for this?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand you correctly. Your just trying to extend the functionality of the carousel indicatores (the bullets at the bottom) to 6 items up from 3 items. Is that right?

Comment: I have a drop down menu that activates a loop that reads the selected array to create the bullets. on array has 5 items, the other 11.

Answer (score 0):

If your just trying to move the carousel to index N, given `class=itemN`. You could try something like this. The only thing you need to account for is the 0 index, so make sure you have a slide with class `'.item0'`

```
 $("[class^=item]").click(function() {
    var index = $(this).attr("class").match(/\d+/);
    $("#myCarousel").carousel(index);
 });
```

Comment: the only part that did not work for me is

$("#myCarousel").carousel(index);

running an alert on $("#myCarousel") comes back as an object object.

Comment: What functionality are you trying to achieve with the alert dialog? The $() jQuery selector returns you a jQuery object of elements matched by your selector. In this case if you need to access the first element returned you could try `alert($("#myCarousel")[0]);`, which will return the first matched element.